# Cannot debug app views in DJANGO project using VSCode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I have created an application using the DJANGO framework to create several API programs.
To do this I created an app that is now in the installed list of apps.

I can debug the manage.py file as the server starts up.
But I cannot debug subsequent calls to views in apps, the views.py breakpoints are never hit?

[image]

However, this is never reached

[image]

This is what my launch JSON looks like:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload"
        ],

        "env": {
            "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "django-sql-project.settings"
          },

        "django": true,
        "justMyCode": true
    }
]
```

}

and my VS Settings json looks like this:

```
{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath":"~//env//Scripts//python.exe",
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
"appService.zipIgnorePattern": [
    "__pycache__{,/**}",
    "*.py[cod]",
    "*$py.class",
    ".Python{,/**}",
    "build{,/**}",
    "develop-eggs{,/**}",
    "dist{,/**}",
    "downloads{,/**}",
    "eggs{,/**}",
    ".eggs{,/**}",
    "lib{,/**}",
    "lib64{,/**}",
    "parts{,/**}",
    "sdist{,/**}",
    "var{,/**}",
    "wheels{,/**}",
    "share/python-wheels{,/**}",
    "*.egg-info{,/**}",
    ".installed.cfg",
    "*.egg",
    "MANIFEST",
    ".env{,/**}",
    ".venv{,/**}",
    "env{,/**}",
    "venv{,/**}",
    "ENV{,/**}",
    "env.bak{,/**}",
    "venv.bak{,/**}",
    ".vscode{,/**}"
]
```

}

Comment: The views are however, successfully being executed since I get the correct responses back.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solved it for me.
To be able to debug apps created and installed in the primary django project, you must add this to your launch.json
[image]

now only does the debugger step into a custom app view:

[image]